# How to Push AOSP Whole Source Code to my Private Github?

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I already cloned latest android source code using

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master`

`repo sync`

how to upload the whole source code to my private github?

Comment: how about creating a fork and cloning that instead?

Comment: Try "repo forall"

Comment: @Yong can you please explain how to do that?
do i need to add the remote url in the manifest file? if you have an example that will be great 
Thanks

Comment: Did you find working steps @Steven?